# PHP exec split command on linux server

Tags: php, linux, split, exec

I have a linux server running ubuntu 10.10 maverick with apache and php installed, in the /var/www directory I have a download directory. I have used OSFile manager and modified to include a function to split files here is the code:

```
function spl($fname){
 global $folder;
 if (!$fname == ""){
    maintop("Split");
    $dirfile = $folder.$fname;

    \\escape directory path
    $dirfile = str_replace(" ","\ ",$dirfile);
    $dirfile = str_replace("(","\(",$dirfile);
    $dirfile = str_replace(")","\)",$dirfile);
    $command = "split -d -b1024m ".$dirfile." ".$fname."_";
    echo "Command: ".$command;
    echo"<br />";


    $returnval =0;
    unset($output2);
    $output = exec($command,$output2,$returnval);

    //echo results
    echo($output);
    echo"<br />";
    print_r($output2);
    echo"<br />";
    echo($returnval);
    echo"<br />";
    mainbottom();
 }
  else
    home();
}
```

The command does not execute. The file and directory is correct but it returns exit code 1, and Array() as the output values,  I have created a group that includes a few users, I have made this group the owner of downloads/ and given it read write and execute permissions, this group includes www-data.

Any Help will be apreciated

Comment: Tip 1: Utilize `addcslashes` or `escapeshellarg`. Tip 2: look into the `error.log` if you don't capture any error messages.

Comment: where is error.log located? I have tried escapeshellarg but it did not do anything to the file path.

Comment: It's a webserver file. Often above the docroot. Escapeshellarg adds single quotes around and backslashes within if needed.

Comment: I read that it is suppose to escape a string that will be passed as a shell command but it did not escape the spaces or (), I have checked /var/log/apache2/error.log but it is empty

Comment: It does not need further escaping if enclosed in single quotes, *which it does do*. If you don't get any log entries, or can't find them, then wrap your exec statement in `exec("sh -c \" $cmd 2>&1\"");`

Comment: I have typed it exactly as you said but the exec statement still does not output anything

Comment: ha! nevermind, it did give output,(I accidentally added a space before the & , I am new to vi) it says permission denied

Comment: Hoora Soldier! It seems to be working, It was trying to write the file to /var/www instead of /var/www/download, I amended the code and it is now generating the parts files.  Would you mind explaining what the 2>&1 does, or just providing a link that will? Also if you care for it post an answer that I may choose to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you don't get any error messages from exec and the error.log stays empty, then use this wrapper for executation:

```
 exec("sh -c \" $cmd 2>&1 \"");
```

The `2>&1` redirects the `stderr` channel to `stdout`, so that it shows up in the result array.
[In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21)

Another option would be [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) where you can read each channel separately, but is more work to set up.

Answer (score 0):

try this file split class

[Split and merge files](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2502-PHP-Split-files-in-pieces-that-can-be-gathered-later.html)

or this using exec 
[Split big files using PHP using exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391304/split-big-files-using-php)

Comment: Hi, I am looking into the class you have linked, will let you know if it works. I was on that question, and I am executing the command correctly( I have tested it in a shell) but it does not work through php